# Why only delete statement is executed?

Tags: sqlite, node-red

Im tryng to execute the following but only the delete statement is executed by the SQLite node

```
msg.topic="DELETE FROM table_a; INSERT INTO Table_a (name) VALUES ('john')"
```

Comment: The SQLite node doesn't support multiple statements in a single message. You need to send each as a separate message to the node.

Comment: I think you got the case wrong for the table name in the update statement. It should be: `INSERT INTO table_a (name) VALUES ('john')`